# Sentence (Words with spaces) as JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am currently building a website, where you can add recipes. For that, the user has to put in ingredients and of coure some sort of description. The ingredients will be written like "cheese, ham, etc." They will be saved and the user is able to push this recipe into his account with a subscription and there everything is saved correctly. The description will be written like "putting the ham into the oven, cut the cheese, etc." and it is saved correctly into the recipe as an array. But when I want to subscribe the recipe nothing works and I am pretty sure, that it is the spaces between the words.

My code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('.button_subscribe').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            RecipeID = $(this).val().split(" ")[0];
            userData = {};
            userData.userID = "<%= user._id %>";
            userData.busername = "<%= user.username %>";
            var x = $(this).val().split(" ");
            var recipeData = {};
            recipeData.recipeID = x[0];
            recipeData.title= x[1];
            recipeData.ingredients= x[2];
            recipeData.description= x[4];
            recipeData.theme = x[5];
            recipeData.difficulty= x[6];


            //Abonnement zur Übersicht hinzufügen
            $.ajax({
                url: '/subscriptions',
                type: 'post',
                contentType: 'application/json',
                data: JSON.stringify(rezeptData),
                success: function (rezeptData) {
                    console.log('success');
                },
                error: function (e) {
                    console.log('error');
                }
            });
        })});
```

I have no idea, why this isnt working. The ingredients are saved correctly and a String can contain a space, right? Space is also a String.
I hope, that somebody will eventuell help me.

Comment: Where does `rezeptData ` come from?

Comment: Could you describe the behavior that you see?   What is the browser posting (use the network tab of developer tools to see)?  Is the user actually the entire recipe into a single textbox/textfield?

Comment: Well pieces from the sentence are stored into the "theme" and "difficulty"-fields. It is like the system doesnt know, where it has to store the values, so it will just cut every different word and store it into every available slot

Comment: As long as this: `data: JSON.stringify(rezeptData),` exists without explanation we won't be able to help you.

Comment: rezeptData is coming from the actual recipe-object. And there, the discription is saved correctly.

Answer (score 2):

When you use `split(" ")` it will divide the string into an array at EVERY space character.  This will prevent you from having any sentences.  I would recommend multiple fields.  If that isn't something you want to use, then you need to define another delimiting character, your sentence will get chopped up.  If you want to check this, you can print out the length of the array `x` and you will see it is much longer than you are currently expecting.